# Emacs replace right square bracket

Tags: emacs, replace

I would like to replace the right square bracket "]" with ",1]". Usually I use M-% to do replacement, but for this case it does not work and gives: No matching parenthis found. I tried to replace left square brackets and it works. Does someone can give me a hint how I can replace right square brackets?
Thanks for help.

Comment: what are you doing exactly? If I just do `M-% ] RET 1] RET` it works fine for me.

Comment: Works for me, too. I only get the message you mention ("no matching...") when I input the `]` and `1]`, but you can ignore this.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Indeed, it works. Obviously I was confused that the cursor didn't jumped immediatly to the first occurrence of ] as it usually did for any other string I replaced. Sorry for bother you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No matching parenthesis found" is a useless warning here. Just ignore it. Consider this warning a bug, as it seems useful only WRT to regexps.